# Who are the names on the lunchboxes?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4 there is 'collectable' lunch boxes which drop random items when opened.

However the other day I noticed one of the lunch boxes had a name on it, and I found another today called 'stan'.

Do these names refer to anything in particular? I suspect they might be developers but without a list of names it's hard to confirm unless someone else has already checked this (or it's confirmed elsewhere in game?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**According to the Fallout Wiki:**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_lunchbox)

> It is currently unknown whether the appearance of decals and names is randomized.

Comment: Also worth noting: The lunchboxes stack in inventory. So, it's likely that each lunchbox is not a unique item. Would require testing, but I wouldn't be surprised if the name on a lunchbox changes every time you drop it and pick it up. Or if not exactly every time, perhaps under certain conditions like reloading the game or being in a different area.

Comment: @Iszi they actually 'lose' the name once opened (but still not picked up) so it's just some kind of weird transparent place holder.

Comment: @Iszi That sounds like something in need of testing. It also sounds like it would clear up the whole "currently unknown" situation.

Comment: @DCShannon If smiley is right, that really won't help much. What would be needed then, is to note names and locations of boxes between (at least) two separate playthroughs and compare them.

Comment: @Iszi I see what you're saying. That seems like a separate thing, but one also in need of checking. If picking up a lunchbox removes the name, then the lunchboxes in your inventory aren't unique items.